# HTML5 reset video and play again

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm using timesheets.js and want to play a HTML5 video when the slider is active. 
I'm using this code:

```
if (document.getElementById("v_"+element.id))
{
video = document.getElementById('v_'+element.id)
video.currentTime = 0;
video.play();
}
```

If I'm not using "video.currentTime = 0;
it works most of the time (except when videos are too long). I have to reset the video so it plays from the beginning. Now it resets the video, but it doesn't play. Any ideas?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This solved it! I changed the `video.currentTime = 0;` to:

```
video.load();
```

Answer (score 58):

While Stichy posted a sufficient answer to his own question, the method `video.load()` causes unnecessary bandwidth to be used as it reloads the video from the server.

Loading videos in particular can pose a heavy load on the server. Consider you could possibly be loading many megabytes each time the video is replayed.

There is also a short period where the user needs to wait for the video to re-download as well.

The solution I have found that works most efficient and smooth is by simply pausing the video before changing the `currenttime` property.

Like so:

```
video.pause();
video.currentTime = 0;
video.play();
```

Comment: video.load() wouldn't replay the video for me in iOS9 but this worked!