# iOS6.1, iPod: Second video does not start at the beginning

Tags: jquery, ios, html, video

I'm developing a video player using jQuery Mobile and am using the following code in one of the pages to embed an HTML5 video:

```
<video id="Video" autoplay controls width="288" height="216">
  <source id="MP4" type="video/mp4">
  <source id="OGG" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I then use the following jQuery code to set/change which video is to be played:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".Video", function(){
  $("#Video").attr("poster", Thumb.jpg);
  $("#MP4").attr("src", Video+".mp4");
  $("#OGG").attr("src", Video+".ogg");
  $("#Video").load();
});
```

When accessed on the iPod, iOS 6.1, the first video plays starting at the beginning. However, after watching a few seconds of the first and then selecting a second video, the second video starts playing at the time point where the first video was stopped instead of from the beginning.

This code always plays back each video from the beginning in Google Chrome and a Nokia Windows phone (haven't had a chance to try any other browsers/devices).

How do I get every video to start from the beginning, on the iPod or any other device?

Answer (score 0):

The sample code to handle the seek-bar:

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById('mediaElementID');
mediaElement.seekable.start();  // Returns the starting time (in seconds)
mediaElement.seekable.end();    // Returns the ending time (in seconds)
mediaElement.currentTime = 122; // Seek to 122 seconds
mediaElement.played.end();      // Returns the number of seconds the browser has played
```

Use this code sample as you need it. Every time user selects a new video, set `currenttime` to `starttime`. It will work for all browsers.

I got this from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) under the heading of **Seeking through media**.

You can check out the more properties of the **HTMLMediaElement** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Didn't help. Tried:

`$("#Video").currentTime=0`
`document.getElementById("Video").currentTime=0`
`$("#Video").currentTime=$("#Video").seekable.start`

and several other combinations to no avail. Second video still starts at the time point the first video was stopped.

Comment: Every browser on iPad has the same behavior or is it the only Safari?

Comment: might be i can help you https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW5

Comment: We were using the Google Chrome browser on the iPod. Didn't try Safari. Works in Google Chrome on the PC.

Comment: Apple documentation and this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646648/html5-reset-video-and-play-again suggest that $('#Video").load() should work in reseting the time, but I'm not having luck with that.