# How to free up memory when changing video?

Tags: javascript

How to free up the memory that takes video when the source changes:

```
var video = document.querySelector('.video');
var nextButton = document.getElementById('next-button');
nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    video.src = videoQueue.shift();
});
```

Comment: The garbage collector should free up the memory automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly unload/destroy a VIDEO element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258587/how-to-properly-unload-destroy-a-video-element)

Answer (score 0):

```
var video = document.querySelector('.video');
var nextButton = document.getElementById('next-button');
nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    video.removeAttribute("src");//This will clear memory
    video.load();//Refresh
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: A quote from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37632682/10967889) _the method video.load() causes unnecessary bandwidth to be used as it reloads the video from the server._

Comment: I don’t quite understand why to use the load() method when adding the src video attribute without loading this method. video.setAttribute('src', videoQueue.shift());

Comment: tested this code, Safari issued a warning: "many memory resources are required"

Comment: nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    video.removeAttribute('src');
    video.setAttribute('src', videoQueue.shift());
});