# How can I play HTML5 video from the start?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I followed a tutorial on YouTube that tells how to play a video on hover and pause it when the mouse is out. The code works like charm but I want to modify it. Currently, the video starts from the same place where we left but I want it to start from 0 every time the user hovers.

```
<script>
const clip = document.querySelectorAll('.clip');
for (let i = 0; i < clip.length; i++) {
    clip[i].addEventListener('mouseenter',
        function(e){
            clip[i].play()
        })
    clip[i].addEventListener('mouseout',
        function(e){
            clip[i].pause()
        })
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try clip[i].currentTime = 0;
Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646648/html5-reset-video-and-play-again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
clip[i].currentTime=0;
clip[i].play();
```